# $M\subseteq p\implies (M)\subseteq p$ where $p$ is a prime ideal, $(M)$ the ideal generated by $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm stuck on this result needed for a larger problem:

Let $M\subseteq R$, $p$ be a prime ideal of $R$ then:
$$M\subseteq p\implies (M)\subseteq p$$
where $(M)$ denotes the ideal generated by $M$. 
I attempted to show a contradiction using ideal properties, but I'm not getting anywhere.

How can the inclusion be derived?

Comment: $p$ is closed under addition and $R$ multiplication. $(M)$ is just the closure of $M$ under those properties, so it remains within $p$. This would work for any ideal $p$, not just a prime one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as @TokenToucan pointed out in the comments this is true for any ideal $I$. If $M \subset R $ which is contained in an ideal $I$ of $R$, then by definition $(M)$ is the intersection of all the ideals of $R$ which contain $M$. Now the ideal $I$ contains $M$ by hypothesis, hence $(M) \subset I$.